# C struct print, decode this code?

Tags: c, memory-address

I am in the process of studying for a test, and I'm trying to work through some practice problems.  I've been working on this a while now..but can't figure it out.  Please take a look at the code fragment:

```
 union {
   int i;
   short x;
   unsigned short u;
   float f;
 } testout;
 testout.i=0xC0208000;
```

Before I ask the question, can someone please explain to me how the above code works??  My guess is that `testout.i=0xC0208000` puts either an int, short, unsigned short, or float and puts the result in that address. (?)

The question is what prints out if we write `printf("%d", testout.x)`?  I know we should expect digits....but I have no idea where they are getting the digits from....there is no output.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you read up on [unions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(computer_science)#C.2FC.2B.2B)?

Comment: You need to know both how unions work, and the endianness of your platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Little Endian machines(x86, x64, etc) the answer would be `-32768`.

Here is the reason for the answer for Little Endian, from which you should be able to figure out the reason for Big Endian.

A `union` stores all its members in the same memory location, the size of which is determined by its maximum sized member. Assuming `sizeof(int)` to be 4 bytes and `sizeof(float)` to be 4 bytes, this means that `testout` members are stored in 4 bytes location. Now since we have Little Endian architecture, the statement `testout.i = 0xC0208000` stored `i` in memory as follows:

- The Least Significant Byte (LSB) `0x00` is stored at the lowest byte address, let assume this address to be `0x123456`.
- `0x80` is stored at the next higher address, i.e. `0x123457`, and `0x20` is stored at the address `0x123458`.
- The Most Significant Byte (MSB) `0xC0` is stored at `0x123459`.

Visually something like this

```
Addresses       ->  0x123459    0x123458    0x123457    0x123456
Binary Values   ->  11000000    00100000    10000000    00000000
Hex Values      ->  0xC0        0x20        0x80        0x00
```

The *key point* here is that **all members of the `union` are stored starting at the same byte address.** Hence when you access `testout.x`, the LSB of `x` is `0x00`, the value at the `0x123456`, and MSB is `0x80`, the value at the next higher address `0x123457`, which gives us a 2 byte representation as `0x8000`, equal to decimal `-32768`.

Answer (score 3):

When you define a union, memory is allocated for the largest type in the union. In your case it is`float`. When you say `testout.i=0xC0208000;` 0xC0208000 is stored in the memory allocated. And when you try to print `testout.x` printf will retrieve 4 bytes(Assuming 4 byte int) of data in the union memory and print it as an integer. You can read up on unions [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm)